# Why were references added to C++? (from the history viewpoint)

Tags: c++, reference

I've read many discussions on the difference between references and pointers and when to use which. They all seem to get their conclusions from analysis of the behaviors of the two.

But I'd still like to know what was in the language designers' mind. What's the main motive for this design? In what typical situation is it intended to be used? Perhaps the answer is already included in the discussions I mentioned, but I want to know which are authentic.

P.S. Does reference have a history as long as pointer in C++? Was it originated from the very beginning or came up as a patch for some situations? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's [Stroustrup's](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#pointers-and-references) reasons for adding them to the language.

Basically they were mainly added to support operator overloading.

Comment: Wow, this is really a direct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

From the [FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references):

> Even though a reference is often
>   implemented using an address in the
>   underlying assembly language, please
>   do not think of a reference as a funny
>   looking pointer to an object. A
>   reference is the object. It is not a
>   pointer to the object, nor a copy of
>   the object. It is the object.

Along with this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)) it should answer some of your questions (most likely except for the history). You can always dig into the standard, but I find it unlikely that there will be any *nice tale* about the origin of references...

Comment: A reference is a pointer. It's quite important to understand that when debugging memory problems etc etc.

Comment: A reference is NOT a pointer, but sometimes is implemented with a pointer behind the scenes. Sometimes it's not, in which case the previous advice will be a major red herring. In particular, temporaries bound to a reference (i.e. `T const& t = T();`) are unlikely to be implemented as a pointer.

Comment: A reference is a pointer that is guaranteed by the compiler not to be null.

Comment: A reference is NOT a pointer. It IS an ALIAS. Thinking of it as a pointer will get you into trouble while debugging. When the code is compiler there may potentially be no pointers anywhere if the optimizer is doing its job. Note: taking the address of a pointer and taking the address of a reference will give you very different things.